# Python: How to Webscrape All Rows from a Specific Table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

For practice, I am trying to webscrape financial data from one table in this url: https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/TSLA/tesla/revenue

I'd like to save the data from the "Tesla Quarterly Revenue" table into a data frame and return two columns: Data, Revenue.

Currently the code as it runs now is grabbing data from the adjacent table, "Tesla Annual Revenue."  Since the tables don't seem to have unique id's from which to separate them in this instance, how would I select elements only from the "Tesla Quarterly Revenue" table?

Any help or insight on how to remedy this would be deeply appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/TSLA/tesla/revenue"

html_data = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'html5lib')

tesla_revenue = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Date", "Revenue"])

for row in soup.find("tbody").find_all("tr"):
    col = row.find_all("td")
    date = col[0].text
    revenue = col[1].text

    tesla_revenue = tesla_revenue.append({"Date":date, "Revenue":revenue},ignore_index=True)

tesla_revenue.head()
```

Below are the results when I run this code:

[image]

Comment: "only 1 row of data is returned" - well, your call to `tesla_revenue.append` is outside your `for row...` loop, so you're only appending the last set of values.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Thank you for taking a look!  Completely missed that myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let pandas do all the work

```py
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/TSLA/tesla/revenue"

tables = pd.read_html(url)
for df in tables:
    # loop over all found tables
    pass

# quarterly revenue is the second table
df = tables[1]
df.columns = ['Date', 'Revenue'] # rename the columns if you want to
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I realized I wasn't properly indexing the element I was trying to grab, this is super helpful.  Much appreciated.